# Add INSERT IGNORE Statement to CAKEPHP saveAll method

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I need to add IGNORE option to saveAll() method in CAKEPHP. I want exact impementation of this . Some other SO questions answered related to validations and isUnique() checking like that. I need to implement this conditions , don't care waht is going on behind .

Please advise me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way that I think this would be possible, other than using the [`execute()`](http://api20.cakephp.org/view_source/dbo-source#l-399) function provide by your data source is if you extended the `Mysql` datasource class and changed the behaviour of the [`create()`](http://api20.cakephp.org/view_source/dbo-source#l-944) and [`renderStatement()`](http://api20.cakephp.org/view_source/dbo-source#l-1689) functions to includes case where you want it to append the `IGNORE` SQL keyword.

You'd want to place the data source file in `APP/Model/Datasource/` and have it extends `Mysql` (assuming you use CakePHP 2+).  Have a look at the 2 functions above.  I'd just create a case where if uses 'createignore' instead of 'create' when calling `renderStatement()` when a certain option is passed to `create()`.

That said, there most likely is a way to achieve what you're trying to do without going through that much trouble. If you elaborate on what you're trying to do, I might be able to give you a better answer.

Comment: I am using cake 1.3.X . I've had checked these functions . I am ready extend the codebase

Comment: @duke - So if you're already extending the codebase, why can't you do what I wrote above? The files for 1.3 are almost identical. You'll want to extends `DboMysql` or `DboMysqli` depending on which one you're using. I forgot to mention, you'll need to update the config file in `APP/config/database.php` to point to your newly create datasource.